# Azure storage authorization failed or format is wrong

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, azure, storage

Good day everybody, I'm stuck with authorization on azure storage. When I am uploading only one file(blob) I put SAS key in the url and everything works fine. But when I need to create chunks in BLOB service, there must be Authorization header(Amazon says that) when creating them. I am trying to use [this article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/fileservices/Authentication-for-the-Azure-Storage-Services?redirectedfrom=MSDN) to create authorization.

There is my JavaScript code(I use ng-file-uploader library):

```
    $scope.upload = function (file) {
    blockId = blockId + 1;
    Upload.upload({
        url: "https://MYSTORAGENAME.blob.core.windows.net/kont1/"+ file.name + "?comp=block&blockid=" + blockId,
        method: 'PUT',
        resumeChunkSize: '40MB', // upload in chunks of specified size
        headers: {
            'Content-type': 'multipart/form-data',
            'Authorization': 'SharedKey' + "MYSTORAGENAME:iDrJ7OuggJ8uoIn5olNDeOvSAoMrpqckl5mUaT5/H/w=",
            'x-ms-version': '2015-12-11',
            'x-ms-date': new Date().toUTCString()
            },
        data: {file: file}
    }).then(function (resp) {
        console.log('Success ' + resp.config.data.file.name + 'uploaded. Response: ' + resp.data);
    }, function (resp) {
        console.log('Error status: ' + resp.status);
    }, function (evt) {
        var progressPercentage = parseInt(100.0 * evt.loaded / evt.total);
        console.log('progress: ' + progressPercentage + '% ' + evt.config.data.file.name);
    });
};
```

This request returns: **400 (Authentication information is not given in the correct format. Check the value of Authorization header.)**

When I try to change this:
**'Authorization': 'SharedKey' + "MYSTORAGENAME:iDrJ7OuggJ8uoIn5olNDeOvSAoMrpqckl5mUaT5/H/w="**

to this:
**'Authorization': "SharedKey sand2storage:iDrJ7OuggJ8uoIn5olNDeOvSAoMrpqckl5mUaT5/H/w="**

Then it returns: **403 (Server failed to authenticate the request. Make sure the value of Authorization header is formed correctly including the signature.)**

I spent 2days on this and still can't get it right, maybe somebody see's what I am missing? Thank you in advance.

NOTE:

> iDrJ7OuggJ8uoIn5olNDeOvSAoMrpqckl5mUaT5/H/w=

I generate this key in Azure page each try to make it sure that key is correct.

[image: Image when generating key from Azure site]

Comment: Could you please share how are you calculating the `SharedKey` value?

Comment: I just take the sig value from generated "Shared access signature ". Look at the picture I inserted at the end of the question.

Comment: Also I tried to generate it using azure node library :

var blobSvc = azure.createBlobService("STORAGE_NAME","ACCESS_KEY","https://STORAGE_NAME.blob.core.windows.net");
    var startDate = new Date();
    var expiryDate = new Date(startDate);
    expiryDate.setMinutes(startDate.getMinutes() + 800);

    var ap = {
    AccessPolicy: {
        Permissions: azure.BlobUtilities.SharedAccessPermissions.WRITE,
        Start: startDate,
        Expiry: expiryDate
    },
    };
    var token = blobSvc.generateSharedAccessSignature('CONTAINER_NAME', 'myblob', ap);

Comment: About how to generate shared key please refer to this post: [Authentication for the Azure Storage Services](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/fileservices/Authentication-for-the-Azure-Storage-Services?redirectedfrom=MSDN)

Comment: Thanks for help. But even if I generated the key I still was getting the same error. Gaurav Mantri solution worked for me in many ways. As I experienced, the problem could be that I was free trial user.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you're using `Shared Access Signature (SAS)`, then you don't need to specify the `Authorization` header as the SAS token contains this value. You also need not define `x-ms-version` and `x-ms-date` headers. What you do need to include is `x-ms-blob-type` request header and set its value to `BlockBlob`.

What you would need to do is take the SAS token and append that to your URL (please make sure that you don't include the `?` in the SAS Token.

Assuming you're storing the Sas Token from portal in a variable called `sasToken`, your code would be:

```
$scope.upload = function (file) {
    blockId = blockId + 1;
    Upload.upload({
        url: "https://MYSTORAGENAME.blob.core.windows.net/kont1/"+ file.name + "?comp=block&blockid=" + blockId + "&" + sasToken,
        method: 'PUT',
        resumeChunkSize: '40MB', // upload in chunks of specified size
        headers: {
            'Content-type': 'multipart/form-data',
            'Authorization': 'SharedKey' + "MYSTORAGENAME:iDrJ7OuggJ8uoIn5olNDeOvSAoMrpqckl5mUaT5/H/w=",
            'x-ms-version': '2015-12-11',
            'x-ms-date': new Date().toUTCString()
            },
        data: {file: file}
    }).then(function (resp) {
        console.log('Success ' + resp.config.data.file.name + 'uploaded. Response: ' + resp.data);
    }, function (resp) {
        console.log('Error status: ' + resp.status);
    }, function (evt) {
        var progressPercentage = parseInt(100.0 * evt.loaded / evt.total);
        console.log('progress: ' + progressPercentage + '% ' + evt.config.data.file.name);
    });
};
```

Comment: One more thing for others who will need this. Block id must be in base64 format :)

Comment: In my case I need to set only one header: `'x-ms-blob-type': 'Blockblob'`, and I had to remove Authorization, x-ms-date and x-ms-version